# Starting up PySpark for using python with Spark in eclipse

Tags: python, apache-spark

how do i use python for a Spark program in eclipse?
I've installed PyDev plugin in eclipse and installed Python on the system but how do i use PySpark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Spark Python programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html)

To run an interactive Python Spark interpreter, build Spark, then run:

```
./bin/pyspark
```

from within the Spark installation.

PySpark can also be used from standalone Python scripts by creating a SparkContext in your script and running the script using `bin/pyspark`.

One can also launch PySpark in IPython, the enhanced Python interpreter - see the programming guide for details.

Comment: How do i "Build Spark" from the command prompt ?
Also , when i try to build script on eclipse, it gives an unresolved import error at this line :

from pyspark import SparkContext

Comment: See the build instructions on the [overview page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/index.html) of the Spark website - just run `sbt/sbt assembly` (may take quite a long time)

Comment: I haven't tried developing pyspark apps in Eclipse, but I expect you need to add the pyspark libraries to Eclipse's PYTHONPATH

Comment: According to the programming guide, I just run "IPYTHON=1 $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark" from prompt

Answer (score 6):

I started a new Python project in PyDev, then went into Project -> Properties -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH -> External libraries. I added a "source path" entry for

> /path/to/spark/spark-0.9.1/python

This allowed PyDev to see all Spark-related code and provide auto complete, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user1779385: For setting up development environments, you could follow this guide: http://www.slideshare.net/prossblad/install-eclipse-for-sparkpython-49100874